# How to change seaborn violinplot legend labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I'm using seaborn to make a violinplot, which uses hues to identify who survived and who didn't. This is given by the column 'DEATH_EVENT', where 0 means the person survived and 1 means they didn't. The only issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to set labels for this hue legend. As seen below, 'DEATH_EVENT' presents 0 and 1, but I want to change this into 'Survived' and 'Not survived'.

[image: Current plot image.]

Current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
sns.set()
plt.style.use('seaborn')
data = pd.read_csv('heart_failure_clinical_records_dataset.csv')

g = sns.violinplot(data=data, x='smoking', y='age', hue='DEATH_EVENT')
g.set_xticklabels(['No smoking', 'Smoking'])
```

I tried to use: `g.legend(labels=['Survived', 'Not survived'])`, but it returns it without the colors, instead a thin and thick line for some reason.

[image: (image).]

**I'm aware I could just use:**

```
data['DEATH_EVENT'].replace({0:'Survived', 1:'Not survived'}, inplace=True)
```

but I wanted to see if there was another way. I'm still a rookie, so I'm guessing that there's a reason why the CSV's author made it so that it uses integers to describe plenty of things. Ex: if someone smokes or not, sex, diabetic or not, etc. Maybe it runs faster?

Comment: You can almost always change anything about a matplotlib figure after it's been created. Some things are easy and obvious, others are tricky. Changing legend texts is possible but a little tricky. The right answer here is to give seaborn the labels you want to use. (It's not necessary to modify the original dataframe inplace, just call `replace` on the object that you pass to seaborn.)

Comment: @mwaskom Would there be a way to remove the legend title without the trick of introducing a column with an empty name (and without accessing `ax.legend_` as in `ax.legend_.set_title('')`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controlling Seaborn legends is still somewhat tricky (some extensions to matplotlib's API would be helpful).  In this case, you could grab the handles from the just-created legend and reuse them for a new legend:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"smoking": np.random.randint(0, 2, 200),
                     "survived": np.random.randint(0, 2, 200),
                     "age": np.random.normal(60, 10, 200),
                     "DEATH_EVENT": np.random.randint(0, 2, 200)})
ax = sns.violinplot(data=data, x='smoking', y='age', hue='DEATH_EVENT')
ax.set_xticklabels(['No smoking', 'Smoking'])
ax.legend(handles=ax.legend_.legendHandles, labels=['Survived', 'Not survived'])
```

[image: violinplot with changed legend]

Here is an approach to make the change via the dataframe without changing the original dataframe. To avoid accessing `ax.legend_` alltogether (to remove the legend title), a trick is to rename the column to a blank string (and use that blank string for `hue`). If the dataframe isn't super long (i.e. not having millions of rows), the speed and memory overhead are quite modest.

```py
names = {0: 'Survived', 1: 'Not survived'}
ax = sns.violinplot(data=data.replace({'DEATH_EVENT': names}).rename(columns={'DEATH_EVENT': ''}),
                    x='smoking', y='age', hue='')
```

Comment: Doing pandas operations `inplace` almost never actually confers a memory benefit relative to making a transient new object that then gets garbage collected after the plot is made: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Comment: OK, I see. Pandas is doing a lot of internal optimizations which are hard to guess without diving into its source code, and which will probably change in the future.  I removed the last part of my post.