# Label mean in pyplot.violinplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a pyplot.violinplot and would like to display the mean, and label it as such in the legend, like so: (this is example data, mine is different)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plotData = [np.random.normal(loc = i,size = 100) for i in range(0,3)]
plotPos = range(0,3)
plt.violinplot(plotData,plotPos,showmeans=True,showextrema=False,widths=1,bw_method=0.5)
plt.legend(labels=['distribution','mean'])
```

[resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PsVF.png)

However, the legend references the distribution twice, and doesn't label the mean line. I figured out that because there are 3 violins, the first three items to be labeled in the legend are the distributions, and the forth is the mean line, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0kMl.png). But I want to skip two of the distributions and just have the one distribution and one mean line in the legend.

I also tried saving the figure to a variable and referencing specific handles, according to the [matplotlib.pyplot.legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) like so:

```
violin = plt.violinplot(plotData,plotPos,showmeans=True,showextrema=False,widths=1,bw_method=0.5)
plt.legend(handles=violin['cmeans'],labels=['mean'])
```

but it says `'LineCollection' object is not iterable` so I'm just not sure how to use that here.

I saw a similar problem in the seaborn.violinplot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846287/how-to-change-seaborn-violinplot-legend-labels) but it didn't answer my question either. There is also guidance for using handles to label different lines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390421/matplotlib-legend-not-working-correctly-with-handles), but this question is different because of the `'LineCollection' object is not iterable` error I'm running into when using handles.

Answer (score 0):

The `handles` argument in `pyplot.legend` is expecting a list of arguments, so when I passed `violin['cmeans']` it was trying to iterate over it (but it couldn't). I fixed it by calling it like so:

```
plt.legend(handles = [violin['cmeans']],labels=['mean'])
```

resulting in [the expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5ZwN.png).